# Output returned data in current div

Tags: jquery

I have an ajax form where I output data returned via PHP script using this line of code:

```
jQuery(".commentfeedback").html(data);
```

That outputs it to div with class `commentfeedback`. Instead, I want to simply output it in the current div, so I tried:

```
jQuery(this).html(data);
```

But it did not work. What am I doing wrong?

Complete JS code:

```
jQuery('.commenttopicform').submit(ajaxSubmit);

function ajaxSubmit(){

var commenttopicform = jQuery(this).serialize();

jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "/testrmv/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data: commenttopicform,
    success:function(data){
        jQuery(".commentfeedback").html(data); // empty div to show returned data
    }
});

return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
         <form action="" method="post" class="commenttopicform" />
             <input type="hidden" name="postid" value="<?php echo $t_id; ?>" />
             <input type="hidden" name="action" value="comment_topic" />

             <div class="t_add_com_txt">
                  <textarea name="comment" maxlength="2000" placeholder="Please add a note here..."></textarea> 
             </div>

             <div class="t_add_com_sub">
                  <input type="submit" value="Add Note" class="button-primary newcomsub" name="send" />
             </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: try `jQuery(event.target).html(data);`

Comment: Please show the whole code. Note that `this` is not preserved in closures. You can use the `context:` option to `$.ajax` to pass it along to the callback.

Comment: @salniro That did not work unfortunately.

Comment: @Barmar I have updated my question, can you please show me how to use the context...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `context:` option to pass along the `this` value to the callback.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "/testrmv/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data: commenttopicform,
    context: this,
    success:function(data){
        jQuery(this).nextAll('.commentfeedback').eq(0).html(data); // empty div to show returned data

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tested this but it did not return anything within the current div. Are you certain this code is correct?

Comment: It would be helpful to see more of the code. Maybe `this` isn't really the place you want the data shown in. If this is in a click handler, `this` will be the element you clicked on.

Comment: I have updated my question with the complete jQuery code which contains only a few more lines, are they relevant to solve this issue? Thank you Barmar.

Comment: So `this` is the form. How does the "current div" that you want to put the returned data into relate to the form?

Comment: My problem is that with line: jQuery(".commentfeedback").html(data); -- the data is returned to **all** divs with class 'commentfeedback'. I want it to return to only one of those divs, something like "next() div"... How do I do this?

Comment: Something like `$(this).next().html(data)`.

Comment: Exactly. Although that line is not currently working.

Comment: I really need to see your exact HTML, so I know the correct DOM traversal functions.

Comment: There's no `commentfeedback` DIV in the HTML.

Comment: Sorry the 'commentfeedback' div is placed right underneath the form tag.

Comment: Very nice, works fine. It seems it was an issue of duplicate function names that conflicted with this working.